# Run a shell command and interact with it from a view

Tags: swiftui

I want to create a sort of GUI for the CLI version of 7Zip for macOS. I have managed to run the task and get the stdout/stderr and also write to stdin when the task awaits for user inputs (for example: confirmation of overwriting).

How can I show an Alert() or a dialog with multiple buttons when the task awaits for input?

The following generic function gets a string as args: for example `x file.zip -o /output/folder` and return the output or error.

If 7zip asks for user input the string will always finish with a ?, when that is printed, I want to show a dialog or Alert() with multiple buttons and write the response to the console for the task to continue.

Here is what I have got so far:

```swift
 func runShellCmd(args: [String]) -> String{
        let task = Process() //create the task
        var consoleLog:String = ""
        // get the pipes ready
        let stdOutPipe = Pipe() 
        let stdErrPipe = Pipe()
        let stdInPipe = Pipe()
        task.standardOutput = stdOutPipe
        task.standardError = stdErrPipe
        task.standardInput = stdInPipe
        

        task.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/whatever/7zz")
        
        task.arguments = args
        
        let stdout = stdOutPipe.fileHandleForReading
        let stdin = stdInPipe.fileHandleForWriting
        
        //Printing the stdout
        stdout.readabilityHandler = { pipeOut in
            if let out = String(data: pipeOut.availableData, encoding: .utf8) {
                if !out.isEmpty {
                    consoleLog += out
                    print("\(out)") 
                    //7zip asks for user input always with a "? "
                    if(out.hasSuffix("? ")){
                        //Show Alert here with different choices
                        var choice = //return choice from Alert
                        //Close the alert and write to console
                        stdin.write("\(choice)\n".data(using: .utf8)!) 
                    }
                }
            } else {
                print("ERROR: \(pipeOut.availableData)")
            }
            
        }
        
        try! task.run()
        
        let stderr = stdErrPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
        let error = String (data: stderr, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
        
        task.waitUntilExit()
        
        if(!error!.isEmpty){
            return error!
        }
        return consoleLog //return the entire stdout for further processing
    }
```

I have tried to insert a var of type bool (after the ? is printed) and set it true to show a .alert in my view but that shows only if the task has exited.